# Best practice for coding async web service calls on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, web-services, asynchronous

I have an iPhone app that talks to a web services, and pulls data from the web service to the devices.  Pushes the data into core data, and then updates the GUI.

The process of doing this is as follows :

1. GUI event creates a call to a transaction layer (model).
2. Transaction layer (model) creates a async call to the web service.
3. Response received from web service, parsed by transaction layer (check for error).  Push results into core data.
4. Sends a notification (either error or non-error) for GUI to update.

I have a lot of these async calls, to refresh different parts of the data.  And my GUI clients are subscribed to a number of these notifications.

What I am finding, is that the code on the GUI side is a bit confusing when I go back to debug.  Because actions are triggered by notifications.

What I would really like to do is to have some type of wrapper function around items 2, 3 and 4.  So that the code looks more stream lined.

```
if (![TransactionLayerModelClass getDataFromWebServerWrapper: args]) {
    // error actions
} else {
    // good actions
}
```

I am not even sure this is possible, and have not found any solutions in my googling.  But if it is, I think it would significantly improve the readability of my code.

Answer (score 2):

To write code that looks the way you'd want, you'd want to use blocks:

```
[TransactionLayerModelClass 
     getDataFromWebServerWrapper: args
     errorBlock:^(NSError* error)
        {
           // error actions
        }
     successBlock:^(NSData* data)
        {
           // good actions
        }];
```

Blocks are only available when targeting iOS 4 and above.  They're very useful, and while they are easy to abuse and misuse, this is one of their ideal applications when implemented properly.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html

Comment: Adpalumbo, I read a little about blocks, and I am not sure I fully understand your response yet.  Are you saying to use blocks in the call to the webserver (instead of the normal async requestCompleted and requestCompleted with Error).  Or are you saying that I should provide a errorBlock and a successBlock to the TransactionLayerModel class function.  Are there some good examples of this out there?  Tried googling, but still finding the standard call back implementations for web services.

Comment: @Yenyi Well, if you want your code to look like your example, you'd start by updating TransactionLayerModelClass to accept blocks like these as part of getDataFromWebServerWrapper:.  You'd then retain these blocks, and call them when the associated web service request completes, either instead of or in addition to the notifications you're currently posting.  The blocks are basically just a way for you to pass an entire code segment from your GUI down to your model or web service layer without those layers needing to know anything about your GUI.